# Eslint and Prettier lines formatting issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, prettier

who faced with same issue? My IDE (JetBrain WebStorm, macOS) consider the code snippet at the screenshot below as a wrong formatted one:

[image]

But my teammate has JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA on Windows, and the same code is OK for the same linter!

We use the same environment for linters (.eslintrc, .prettierrc, .editorconfig, etc.).
In the same time, my IDE does not refer to the rule it's trying to use, it just shows me this hint:

`ESLint: Insert`⏎·····`(prettier/prettier)`

Do you know what can it be?

The code is here (JSX, React):

```
const DBFieldInfoBlock = ({
  rowClassName,
  cellLabelClassName,
  cellValueClassName,
  id,
  value,
  currency,
}) => (
  <div className={rowClassName}>
    <span className={cellLabelClassName}>
      <InfoLabel id={id} />:
    </span>
    {value !== undefined && value !== null && (
      <span className={cellValueClassName}>
        <InfoValue value={value} id={id} currency={currency} />
      </span>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: add return inside ?? and grab with ()

Comment: Freestyle09 what do you mean?

Comment: WebStorm has it's own code styling, different on mac and different on Windows... I'm trying to understand what you are doing and I think you should add some () in there... 1.) {(value !== undefined && value !== null) && ( return (<span>...</span>))} try something like this

Comment: Or paste code, I will check on my mac

Comment: Added just now.

Comment: try vscode. run perfectly on MacOs for JS react

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
Guys, perhaps it will be helpful for someone.
I proceeded following steps:

1. Delete the repo.
2. Clone the repo again.

That's it!